# log.entering / log.exiting prints org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources loadLocale

Tags: struts

When I try to log method entering and exiting using `log.entering(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);` or `log.exiting(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);` I see console message as

> PropertyMessa W org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources loadLocale   Resource ../resources/ApplicationResources_en.properties Not Found.

While all other logging works perfectly. Please advice how to remove this message from console.

Answer (score 1):

To remove this message from the console, in

> struts-config.xml

add the code snippet as `<message-resources parameter="...resources.ApplicationResources_en_US" />` with in `<struts-config></struts-config>`

And place the file

> ApplicationResources_en_US in class path..

this message vanishes.